# How to prove that a PDF document is indeed generated from using the knitr library?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I'm currently working on an assignment from the Coursera Data Science Specialization course.

One of the requirements of this assignment is the result PDF report mus be generated using the **knitr** library.

What is the best solution to fulfill this requirements?
One of the solutions I can think of is to do a **sessionInfo** output at the end of my report, but the maximum number of pages allowed for the report is 5 pages and I am trying to avoid doing this.

Any suggestions? Thanks very much!

Comment: Normally the metadata of a PDF has a so called "Producer" entry that tells you which software was used to produce the PDF.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, thanks for your comment. The report will usually be asseseed by peers within the browser and I'm afraid most or all of them won't be bothered or even know how to check the metadata of the PDF document.

Comment: Is that important? If they want to check if your PDF was actually created with this or that tool, the "burden of proof" is on them, not on you. Adding whatever text to the PDF isn't proving anything. You could create a PDF with iText and write on the page that it was created by knitr (e.g. by faking sessioninfo). They'd still have to check the PDF to find out if you're telling the truth.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and feedback Bruno!

Comment: Would it not also be relevant to be able to see the source that generated the PDF? You could put a URL to the source in the source so that it appears in the PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno's point is well-taken: the Producer line is where the info will be found. If there's a requirement that the document be produced by knitr, then whoever is interested in verifying that will know to look at the Producer info.

You can verify that easily enough with your own testing. Once you have generated your PDF output via knitr, open it in Acrobat or Reader, press Ctrl+D to bring up the Document Properties popup window, and select the Description tab. You should find knitr mentioning itself by name there.